# What is the most effective way to put paneling on old style red brick

Tags: mold, moisture, old-house, vapor-barrier

I live in an old cottage style house. The exterior is old red brick, I call it old red brick because I'm sure it's not used no more it is about the size of a cinder block. When built there is literally no wall on the inside of brick just glue and paneling no surfing strips. Front of house sits fairly close to ground. I am having issues in certain places where paneling is coming lose and feels wet. I want to apply new paneling with furring strips and possibly some liquid nail to adhere better on strips. But my big concern is moisture getting between possibly causing same issue again. Or will having some space between the 2 solve the problem

Comment: Find and fix the moisture problem first.  Might have a leak, might just need sealing, maybe just vapour barrier.

Comment: *'old red brick … about the size of a cinder block'* That is absolutely colossal for a brick. Bricks are heavy. The idea is that the bricklayer can lift one in one hand, so he doesn't have to put his trowel down. Pictures might help, because the description alone doesn't really give anough clues.

Comment: I've seen bricks that large, or it could some form of hollow tiles.

Comment: Depending on the local weather, might want to check/add insulation before putting inside wall back up, after moisture is taken care of.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like clay structural tile (which is hollow, albeit different pattern than how a cinderblock is hollow,) and were quite common at one time (still made, but less commonly used now.)

Comment: I believe it is like clay brick, because the plumbing in the ground from house to main is all clay (terra cotta) pipe. To me it seems very fragile.